# can Where/Whereas be used interchangeably in the following examples?

Tags: grammaticality, differences, conjunctions

> *"Whereas there were once as many as fifteen thousand divers on the island, there are now only about five thousand."*
>
> *"Where there were once as many as fifteen thousand divers on the island, there are now only about five thousand."*

I know that "**whereas**" is supposed to be used when contrasting, but when I switched it with "**where**" in this example it still made sense.
So my question is
..... are these two sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: Where can refer to a geographical location or be used for a situation/context/etc, so when talking about an island it could mean either.

Comment: whereas is used in comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

Both words can be used here. Collins Cobuild picks up on this reasonably common usage of **where**:

> *where*
>
> ... 5. [conjunction]
>
> You use *where* to introduce a clause that contrasts with the other
> parts of the sentence.
>
> - *Where some would have given up, she and her coach were determined to lift their game.*
> - *Sometimes a teacher will be listened to, where a parent might not.*

[[COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/where)]

[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/where) is clear here:

> *where* [conjunction]  ... 3. Whereas:
>
> - *That model has an attractive design, where this one is more dependable.*

I'll admit that I'd use 'while' in AHD's example, as it both compares (two pluses) and contrasts (pluses / drawbacks).

Fleshed out, 'in situations / a situation where' or in OP's example 'The situation once being that', followed by a contrasting second statement ... but then these would sound clunky. In fact, OP's second variant sounds stylistically better to my ears.